# Laravel - if condition for select

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement, select, input

My if condition for selected Input is not showing anyhing. Here is my `create.blade.php`:

```
...
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'PostsController@store', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
   <div class="column">
      <label for="title">Title</label></br>
      <input name="title" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control">
   </div>
   </br>
   <div class="column">
      <label for="brand">Brand</label></br>
      <select class="form-control" id="soflow" name="brand">
         <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
         <option value="Volkswagen">Volkswagen</option>
         <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
         <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   </br>
   @if(Input::has('brand') == 'Volkswagen')
      <div class="column">
         <label for="model">Model</label></br>
         <select class="form-control" id="soflow" name="model">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
            <option value="Golf1">Golf 1</option>
            <option value="Golf2">Golf 2</option>
            <option value="Golf3">Golf 3</option>
        </select>
     </div>
   @endif
{!! Form::close() !!}
...
```

But after this my select for model is not showing at all and I just need to show specific models if select input(brand) is for Volkswagen. Any solutions? Please help. Thank you!

Comment: Does the user submit the form after they have selected the brand or after they have selected the model?

Comment: The correct way of this is javascript because you should do it in client side. when brand change event happens then do something with the help of javascript. But if you wanna do it in server side then when brand change event happens you have to submit a form with get method something like this /some/link?brand=volkwagen then you can check @if(request()->brand == 'volkswagen') // your code @endif. in your solution Input doesn't contain brand.

Comment: After they selected the model.
Ozal you are right, it must be done with javascript. Do you have any source code or tutorial, anything that can help me with this? I'm a bit amateru with JS, and I only need this for my project.

Answer (score 0):

i think the solution for your problem can be chained js https://appelsiini.net/projects/chained/ . I am not sure if this works for you. Let me know if it worked.

Comment: I'm on it. I'll let you know as soon as I finish it

Comment: I tried everything, with shorter version and with Ajax, but it is not working...
I added script in my ```create.blade.php``` and links for scripts and install everything throw npm but still not working...

Comment: https://unpossiblepog.blogspot.com/2018/07/add-states-in-dropdown-when-nation-is.html This is the solution!

Answer (score 0):

```
Input::has('brand')
```

shall return T/F if there is an input field with name 'brand' or not. The line,

```
Input::has('brand') == 'Volkswagen'
```

in your logic, evaluates to

```
true == 'Volkswagen'
```

Try

```
@if(Input::get('brand')=='Volkswagen')
```